# Converting UTM coordinates to lat/long

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, utm

I have a dataframe which contains easting and northing columns from Sweden which cuts across 32 to 35 UTM zones

```
library(oce)
sweden_Utm_converted <- utm2lonlat(Sweden_MM$east, Sweden_MM$north, zone =33, hemisphere = "N") #convert easting and Northing columns to lat/long
```

but this code does not classify the dataframe into the 4 UTM zones coordinates might fall into and automatically converts the coordinates using the UTM zone 33

[image: sample data]

```
1224811 6534899
1302992 6528556
1300748 6432977
1415499 6514773
1415499 6514773
1223433 6540588
1291574 6560289
```

Comment: Do you have a field with the UTM zone?

Comment: no. I don't know the zone, but from a UTM map, I think it would between 32 and 35 for Sweden. Still not getting the expected lat/longs when I do the conversion though.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Each UTM zone has 6 degrees of longitude in width, and the x coordinate is the distance between the position and the beginning of the position, so without the zone is mostly guessing

Comment: so is there no way to extract the zones from the UTM coordinates knowing the country they are in before doing the conversion to lat/long?

Comment: Can you show us some of the numbers you do have, and where you expect them to be on the map? Or, if locations are sensitive, similar numbers?

Comment: i just added this to the question

Comment: @UmehBlessing some countries have more than one UTM zone, that's why is so important to know the zone more than the country

Comment: I've typed the numbers in because its then easy for anyone to copy-paste them into test code. I've left the image in for now in case I've made mistakes and people can check.

Answer (score 2):

If those coordinates are UTM zone 35, then according to the code in `utm2lonlat`, they should be here, mostly in Russia:

[image]

Zone 31 puts the points mostly in southern Sweden:

[image]

If all your points are in the same zone, and this looks like the right place for these points, then they will all be zone 31. If you have a mix of zones in your data with no indicator of which is which, then you'll have to guess or figure it out somehow, for example converting via all the reasonable zones and using the one that generates lat-longs nearest Sweden.